# Jquery only works in android mobile dynamically not working on IOS

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
```

this code is not working but

`$("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");`

Its working only in Android device but not working on IOS device

Answer (score 0):

The lines are same! Following code works on iOS.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <label for="ch">Option</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="ch"/>
  <button id="b">Check</button>
  <script>
      $("#b").click(function() {
          $("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");
      });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: sorry... actully i am saying that (Jquery mobile)    $("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh"); its working only in Android device but not working on IOS device & not working on both device attr().  ---> $("input[type='checkbox']").attr("checked",true).checkboxradio("refresh");

Comment: The example above works for me on desktop, Android and iOS as well. Have you tried it? It works with prop() as well as with attr(). I also updated the example for jQueryMobile and it also works like a charm.